# Is ActiveRecord lying?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

My ActiveRecord is not telling the truth. See for yourself:

```
> User.posts.class
  => Array
> User.posts.all.class
  => Array
> a = Array.new
> a.class
 => Array 
> a.all
  NoMethodError: undefined method `all' for []:Array
```

There is no `Array#all` method, so `User.posts` can't be an `Array`. What is going on here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this is the way that associations are implemented in rails. they are lazy proxy objects.

have a look at the documentation for further infos on this: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/associations/collection_proxy.rb#L25

Answer (score 1):

Ruby has a notion of singleton methods. This means that objects can change the behaviour defined by their class. Read [this](http://www.rubyist.net/~slagell/ruby/singletonmethods.html).